# Comparator in backbone requires the sort call when adding a new model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I defined the Comparator in my Backbone.Collection.

When I add a model to the that collection should I call the sort method?

```
this.collection.add(this.newModel);
this.collection.sort(); // should I add this line?
```

According the documentation not, but my app seems to need it. any idea?

---

I added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpn3g/375/)..but I have another problem...any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @fguillen I added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpn3g/375/)..but I have another problem...any idea how to fix it?

Comment: You were using old-fashion Backbone version. Check [my jsFiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/t5ptL/) it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be needed to call `sort()`, the `comparator()` method is used in every Collection insert.

Check the [working example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/t5ptL/)

Your problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: yes you are right for sure. now I need to find where is the issue. Any idea how can I found it?

Comment: try to reproduce the issue with as less code as possible and replicate it in a jsFiddle. It is the only way we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

No, use the negative sign when you return an object from your comparator function. This is another way to sort elements.

```
  //Model
     comparator: function(activity){

                var date = new Date(activity.get('created_at'));
                return -date.getTime();

            }

//View
 events : {
        'click .refresh' : 'refresh',
        'click .reverse' : 'reverse'
    },

    refresh : function() {

     this.collection.fetch();
    console.log('refresh', this.collection);
     this.render();

    },

    reverse : function() {

        var $ref = $(".notifyRefresh");

        console.log("you clicked reverse");

        console.log(this.collection, "collection");

        this.collection.sort();
    }
```

Comment: I am already using the negative sign. In fact, when I fetch the first time the collection the data are sorted. but when I try to add the model I get the problem. If I call the sort method, it works!!

Comment: Yes, you would have to call .sort() then. I do it in my view.

Comment: but according the doc sort is needed only when you set attributes on existing model! I added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cpn3g/375/)..but I have another problem...any idea how to fix it?